# Remove first 10 and last 10 values

Tags: r

I have a file that contains multiple individuals and multiple values for the same individual.
I need to remove the first 10 and last 10 values of each individual, putting all the leftover values in a new table.

This is what my data kinda looks like:

```
Cow        Data   
NL123456   123
NL123456   456
```

I tried doing a for-loop, counting per individual how many values there were (but I think, I already got stuck there, because I am not using the right command I think? All variables in Cow are a factor).
I figured removing the first and last had to be something like this:
`data1[c(11: n-10),]`

Comment: Can you put example of your data using `dput()` function? `dput(head(data1, 50))`

Comment: do you always have more than 20 values ?

Comment: Have a look at function `head`. If you post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) we will be able to help you more

Comment: How do you determine the first 10 and last 10 observations? Is this based on the order they appear in the data? It'd be helpful to know if you have another field, say _observation id_, to which you can "order" the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you always have more than 20 datapoints by cow you can do the following, illustrated on the `iris` dataset :

```
library(dplyr)

dim(iris)
# [1] 150   5

iris_trimmed <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  slice(11:(n()-10)) %>%
  ungroup()

dim(iris_trimmed)
# [1] 90  5
```

On your data :

```
res <-
  your_data %>%
  group_by(Cow) %>%
  slice(11:(n()-10)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

In base R you can do :

```
iris_trimmed <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(split(iris, iris$Species),
         function(x) head(tail(x,-10),-10)))

dim(iris_trimmed)
# [1] 90  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
idt <- as.data.table(iris)
idt[, .SD[11:(.N-10)], Species]
```

Same logic in `base R`:

```
do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(
    split(iris, iris[["Species"]]), 
    function(x) x[11:(nrow(x)-10), ]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with `dplyr`.

In my example I cut only the first and last values. (you can adapt it by changing 2 with any number in `filter`).

The idea is to add after you `group_by` id the number of row per each observation starting from the top (`n`) and in reverse from the bottom (`n1`), then you simply filter out.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(n=1:n(),
         n1 = n():1) %>% # n and n1 are the row numbers
  filter(n >= 2,n1 >= 2) %>%  # change 2 with 10, or whatever
# filter() keeps only the rows that you want
  select(-n, -n1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
# id value
# <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     6
# 2     1     8
# 3     2     1
# 4     2     2
```

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4)), value=sample(8))
data
#   id value
# 1  1     3
# 2  1     6
# 3  1     8
# 4  1     5
# 5  2     4
# 6  2     1
# 7  2     2
# 8  2     7
```

Comment: don't forget to ungroup to avoid bad surprises :)

Comment: and remove the group from the output :)

Comment: Your solution with slice is waay easier anyway. +1